# set a different Class for Specs on TabHost

Tags: java, android, class, android-tabhost

I'm Trying to set a different Class for Specs on my TabHost, but i had only some errors (log pasted below) 
If i change my `champ.setIndicator("Champion").setContent(R.id.tab1);` and so on for the other tabs it works.
Could someone help me?
MY code:

TabsMain.java

```
package com.girardi.lolguides;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class TabsMain extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabs_main);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();
        TabSpec champ = tabHost.newTabSpec("champ");
        TabSpec equip = tabHost.newTabSpec("item");
        champ.setIndicator("Champion").setContent(new Intent(this, Champion.class));
        equip.setIndicator("Items").setContent(new Intent(this, Equip.class));
        tabHost.addTab(champ);
        tabHost.addTab(equip);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tabs_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Champion.java

```
package com.girardi.lolguides;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Champion extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* First Tab Content */
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("First Tab");
        setContentView(textView);

    }
}
```

Equip.java

```
package com.girardi.lolguides;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Equip extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* Second Tab Content */
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Second Tab");
        setContentView(textView);

    }
}
```

activity_tabs_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TabsMain" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

LOG:

```
05-20 13:51:22.890: D/AndroidRuntime(22816): Shutting down VM
05-20 13:51:22.890: W/dalvikvm(22816): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e832a0)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.girardi.lolguides/com.girardi.lolguides.TabsMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:243)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at com.girardi.lolguides.TabsMain.onCreate(TabsMain.java:23)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
05-20 13:51:22.910: E/AndroidRuntime(22816):    ... 11 more
05-20 13:53:10.655: D/AndroidRuntime(24134): Shutting down VM
05-20 13:53:10.655: W/dalvikvm(24134): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e832a0)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.girardi.lolguides/com.girardi.lolguides.TabsMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at com.girardi.lolguides.TabsMain.onCreate(TabsMain.java:19)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
05-20 13:53:10.665: E/AndroidRuntime(24134):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity should extend TabActivity (which is deprecated) or use Fragments (which is the right way) to use tabs. See [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) for more informations and examples.

EDIT: about layout you can use a relativeLayout like this:

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <android.support.v4.app.TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerlist"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>
             <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

About MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {
    private android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can use also if deprecated? there aren't another way to do?

Comment: well you can use it, but it's better if you use fragments. The support library allows you to use fragments even for pre-honeycomb devices. If you look at the documentation you can find an example of usage.

Comment: I try to explain what is my final idea: I want to have a tab host and under tab ost ListActivity. You Know how to do?